# How to implement sliding expiration authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am using angularjs and need to implement sliding expiration for authentication. When the user logs in the first time the server authenticates the user and redirects them to the SPA. The login session should last 20 if there is no activity. If there is activity then the 20 minutes is reset. On a regular website that is not a SPA the cookie is reset when the user navigates around in the website. In a the angularjs SPA when the user navigates around in the application the cookie is not reset. Is there a way to implement this functionality in angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing cookies should be done via the $cookie service but this service not have properties for setting the expiration. To avoid hard refreshing the page, and losing all data, you could use the [angular-cookies](https://github.com/ivpusic/angular-cookie) module which does implement the functionality to set the expiration timeout.